# Text in Textbox are not clickable. Need assistance for javascript to make it clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new in programming, here is a bit of my JavaScript and HTML code.

I want to make on text in text box click start write (input)(text:User Name) so when i click it I cant write and it's problem.

I got div lLogin and input Login.
When I click on lLogin I want to swap on input Login but not delete my text from that div (lLogin).

```
$("#lLogin").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

It's just to hide, I want to hide it when i start writing and when I click on that text in textbox to give me input.

This is code when i start typing text and it hide text it's okey, but when i click on text i cant type because i need javascript for that.

```
 $("#Login").on('keydown', function(){

        var value = $(this).val().length;

        if (value>0){

            $("#lLogin").hide();

        }else{$("#lLogin").show();}
```

HTML Code:
It's text in textbox. When i start write it's start bluring.
When I click on that text (User Name) in textbox it just select it. I want to make him just visible and clicable. So I need javascript code for that.

```
<div onblur="validation();" id="lLogin" aria-hidden="true" class="hint ellipsis">User Name</div>
```

This is input for textbox and it's works fine.

```
<input id="Login" aria-label="Username" class="field" name="user" value="" spellcheck="false" maxlength="5096" type="text">
```

Comment: Not clear at all what your problem is. We can't help without you providing relevant html and a better description of the problem

Comment: I uploaded html code, maybe you can help me now.
But the problem is just to set that text in text box visible and clickable, when click just to jump on input. (I looking for javascript code if that possible).

Answer (score 0):

just jump to input? Ok use focus.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp

onFocus is event to do somting "on click inside" in text box.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onfocus

But I thing is problem with explanation. Try it please again and try jsfiddle to show to as what you want.